# JQuery: How do I STOP the value in the text box going into negative numbers for this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript and I've picked up some basics already, however I'm trying to figure out how I can stop the text value decrementing past 0 in this specific example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYjeJb 
Do I have to change the conditional statement in some way?

```
    <div id="text">Number of items:<span id="number">9</span><div>

        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>
        <button onclick="javascript:add(-1)">remove only 1</button>




        var currentValue = 9;
            var add = function(valueToAdd){
            currentValue += valueToAdd;
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;
            if (this.currentValue == 0) {
            alert("YOU ARE AT 0 ");
        }
        if (!isNaN(currentValue) && currentValue > 0) {
            // Decrement one
            currentValue - 1;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the current value for zero before setting the 'valueToAdd'

```
var currentValue = 9;
        var add = function(valueToAdd){
          if (this.currentValue == 0) {
                alert("YOU ARE AT 0 ");
                    return
            }
            currentValue += valueToAdd;
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;

            if (!isNaN(currentValue) && currentValue > 0) {
                // Decrement one
                currentValue - 1;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that actually changes your value is this one

```
currentValue += valueToAdd;
```

So, if you check the value thats going to be inserted to `currentValue` before changing it, you could stop the function execution and prevent it from being updated:

```
function(valueToAdd){
      var temp = currentValue + valueToAdd; // calculating the next value
      if (temp < 0) 
        return; // if its a negative value, exit from the function without updating currentValue
      currentValue = temp;
      // other code
}
```

Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbKpMq)

Answer (score 0):

Don't decrement `currentvalue` before you check it!

```
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
    if (this.currentValue == 0) {
    alert("YOU ARE AT 0 ")}
    else{
      currentValue += valueToAdd;
     document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;}

}
```